# create multiple same html page in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am new to Django and I am going to create a website with multiple same html pages. I got a text file which contains the number of how many same html pages is going to create. And the following one is the view.py. And the t=a.split()[7] get the number of pages needed to be created

```
def bb(request):
    form=BBForm(request.POSt or None)
    if(form.is_valid()):
       my_file=open("./input_data.txt",'r')
       a=my_file.read();
       my_file.close();
       t=a.split()[7]
       form.save()
    context={"form":form}
    return render(request,'bb/bb.html',context)
```

And the bb.html is like the following:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
 <input type='submit' value='submit />
</form>
```

If I only use those code, I can generate the website with the form.However, it only appears once. What can I do if I want to create multiple same forms within one html page or multiple html page with the same html code

Comment: Creating multiple html pages I don't thinks a good Idea.  So in  easy way just give a for loop range in t and give <form ...  </form> inside that one

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are trying to achieve. but if you want to loop a form you can do this. (not tested )

edit your context

```
context={"form":form, repeat: t}
```

edit your html

```
{% csrf_token %}

{% for num in repeat %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
{% endfor %}
```